# How do I combine the query from two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have three models that look like this

1. Twit

```
    class Twit < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
    
      has_many :retwits, foreign_key: :twit_id, class_name: "Retwit", dependent: :destroy
    
      has_many :mentions, dependent: :destroy
      
      validates :body, presence: true, length: { maximum: 280 }
    end
```

2. Retwit

```
    class Retwit < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :twit, foreign_key: :twit_id, class_name: 'Twit' 
      belongs_to :retwiter, foreign_key: :retwiter_id, class_name: 'User'
      
      validates :twit, uniqueness: { scope: :retwiter }
    end
```

3. User

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :twits, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :retwits, foreign_key: :retwiter_id, class_name: 'Retwit', dependent: :destroy
    end
```

I want to query for Twits and Retwits where (twit.user = some_user or retwit.retwiter = some_user). I am using this code to do the query, however it becomes an array so I cant user ActiveRecords collection methods on it:

```
    (Twit.where(user: people) + Retwit.where(retwiter: people))
```

I wanna be able to use ActiveRecords collection methods on it like so:

```
    (Twit.where(user: people) + Retwit.where(retwiter: people)).offset(0).limit(5)
```

Which doesn't work since adding the two queries together return an array.
Is it possible to return a collection of Twits and Retwits in one single query? If so, how?

Comment: Not possible, you can use one model `Twit` for both the purposes, just add is_retwit flag in Twit model, and you're good. So that you can identify whether it's Twit or Retwit using a single Twit model.

Comment: Or use single table inheritance. https://medium.com/@ghl234/single-table-inheritance-in-rails-6-emulating-oop-principles-in-relational-databases-be60c84e0126